# Java Spring Boot: Rest Adding Addional Informations to JSON

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am a newbie with Java Spring Boot and I have no idea how to explain my problem shortly, maybe that's the reason why I found no results with google.

I am using Java Spring Boot for an REST Api. These are the results I currently get:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {    
    "dimensionAttributeValue" : [ {   
      "chrValue" : "Nopens, Jakob",    
      "intValue" : null,    
      "decValue" : null,    
      "datValue" : null,    
      "startDate" : null,    
      "_links" : {    
        "self" : {    
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/18995"    
        },    
        "dimensionAttributeValue" : {    
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/18995"    
        },    
        "dimensionAttributeID" : {    
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/18995/dimensionAttributeID"    
        },    
        "lstValue" : {    
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/18995/lstValue"    
        },    
        "masterDataID" : {    
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/18995/masterDataID"    
        }    
      }    
    },...
```

I like to have some additional information’s for the relationship fields, like the following example:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {    
    "dimensionAttributeValue" : [ {   
      "chrValue" : "Nopens, Jakob",    
      "intValue" : null,    
      "decValue" : null,    
      "datValue" : null,    
      "startDate" : null,  
      "dimensionAttributeID" : 5 <--- Like thath
      "_links" : {    
        "self" : {    
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/18995"    
        },    
        "dimensionAttributeValue" : {    
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/18995"    
        },    
        "dimensionAttributeID" : {    
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/18995/dimensionAttributeID"    
        },    
        "lstValue" : {    
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/18995/lstValue"    
        },    
        "masterDataID" : {    
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/18995/masterDataID"    
        }    
      }    
    },...
```

Is there are simple way to add these Information’s, maybe not in `_links` section, but as normal attribute and without writing a controller?

---

Edit:

A part of the Model Class, this is who the field looks:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "DimensionAttribute_ID")
private DimensionAttribute dimensionAttribute;
```

In the database there is just the id of the `DimensionAttribute` stored.

---

Edit 2:

Table DimensionAttributeValue:

```
| DimensionAttributeValue_ID | ChrValue | ... | DimensionAttribute_ID | ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1                          | "some"   | ... | 5                     |
```

Table DimensionAttribute;

```
| DimensionAttribute_ID | name | ...
-------------------------------------
| 5                     | "ok" | ...
```

So it is nice that I get the link to the object. But I like to have the `DimensionAttribute_ID` as attribute as well.

---

Edit 3:

DimensionAttributeValue:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DimensionAttributeValue")
public class DimensionAttributeValue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "DimensionAttributeValue_ID")
    private long dimensionAttributeValueID;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DimensionAttribute_ID")
    private DimensionAttribute dimensionAttributeID;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MasterData_ID")
    private MasterData masterDataID;

    @Column (name = "ChrValue")
    private String chrValue;

    @Column (name = "IntValue")
    private String intValue;

    @Column (name = "DecValue")
    private String decValue;

    @Column (name = "DatValue")
    private String datValue;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "LstValue")
    private DimensionAttributeList lstValue;

    @Column (name = "StartDate")
    private Date startDate;

    public DimensionAttributeValue() {
    }

    public DimensionAttributeValue(DimensionAttribute dimensionAttributeID, MasterData masterDataID, String chrValue, String intValue, String decValue, String datValue, DimensionAttributeList lstValue, Date startDate) {
        this.dimensionAttributeID = dimensionAttributeID;
        this.masterDataID = masterDataID;
        this.chrValue = chrValue;
        this.intValue = intValue;
        this.decValue = decValue;
        this.datValue = datValue;
        this.lstValue = lstValue;
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
...
```

DimensionAttribute:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "DimensionAttribute")
public class DimensionAttribute {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column (name = "DimensionAttribute_ID")
    private long dimensionAttributeID;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Dimension_ID")
    private Dimension dimensionID;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "DataType")
    private String dataType;

    @Column(name = "HasHistory")
    private Boolean hasHistory;

    @Column(name = "IsDiscrete")
    private Boolean isDiscrete;

    @Column(name = "HasTrigger")
    private Boolean hasTrigger;

    @Column(name = "IsMandatory")
    private Boolean isMandatory;

    @Column(name = "AllowInterface")
    private Boolean allowInterface;

    @Column(name = "IsReadOnly")
    private Boolean isReadOnly;
...
```

Comment: Do you have corresponding POJO for `dimensionAttributeValue`?

Comment: It is strongly dependant on the served object so if you want additional information you could extend the class or add fields to it on appropriate level.

Comment: @SharanDeSilva what do you mean with POJO?

Comment: POJO - Plain Old Java Object a normal java class

Comment: Add required fields directly inside `DimensionAttribute` or create a class which has your relationship fields and extend to DimensionAttribute.

Comment: @SharanDeSilva I updated my question to make it more like, the `dimesionAttributeID` is a ManyToOne realtionship, I get the to object, that’s perfect. But I additionally like to get the ID of the object

Comment: The DimensionAttribute class has an ID field. Maybe I should show you how the database looks like. I will edit my post.

Comment: @SharanDeSilva I have updeted the post. Maybe I just don`t understand you. Where would I add the required statement? To the Class Model?

Comment: In DimensionAttribute class do you have DimensionAttributeVaules mapping!!

Comment: No its the other way arround, I have a ManyToOne not a OneToMany mapping. The Mapping is in DimensionAttributeValue not in DimensionAttribute.

Comment: please add DimensionAttributeVaules & DimensionAttribute to question only your mapping part.

Comment: @SharanDeSilva done

Comment: Update your mapping accordingly
`public class DimensionAttributeValue {
    @ManyToOne(mappedBy="dimensionAttribute")
    @JoinColumn(name = "DimensionAttribute_ID")
    private DimensionAttribute dimensionAttribute;
}`


`public class DimensionAttribute {
    @OneToMany
    private List<DimensionAttributeValue> dimensionAttributeValues;
}`

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of doing `REST-Apis` in Spring-boot is to expose a REST Controller in your App, by annotating your controller as `@RestController`

That being said, the standard way of getting `Inputs` to your method and giving back `Response` from your method would be using a Java Object and it would reach the caller in `JSON` format.

So I assume here that you are getting an `JSON` input and need to inject few more values. In that case, you will have to accept `JSON` inputs in form of Java objects and then you can use `setter` methods to include any values further.

**Just a Pseudocode ..**.

```
public MyJavaObject {

  // I assume here that you wanted to inject a link in the JSON which itself is set of Objects
  private List<LinkObject> linkObjectList;

}
```

and then get the `linkObjectList` from your object and set another `LinkObject` .. This way when you turn the java objects to `JSON` you can see your addition there ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the code and you can edit it, then in the class that is returned from the controller add the property you want. E.g.

```
class JSONObject {
 .... // old properties

  // your new property with getter and setter
  private Long dimensionAttributeID;

  public Long getDimensionAttributeID() {
     return dimensionAttributeID;
  }

  public Long setDimensionAttributeID(Long dimensionAttributeID) {
     this.dimensionAttributeID = dimensionAttributeID;
  }
}
```

If you can call the getter of the **DimensionAttributeValue** and the id has getter then your **DimensionAttributeValue** has the id.

Go to the place where the return class object is created and set the property
with the value of getter from **DimensionAttributeValue** as shown below.

```
jsonObjec.setDimensionAttributeID(dimensionAttributeValue.getDimensionAttributeID().getDimensionAttributeID());
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also make a corresponding DTO for the Entity?
If yes,  you just have to add the attribute dimensionAttributeID
to the DTO and return the JSON object of DTO.  Meanwhile Map the DTO with your Entity too.

Your DTO class will look something like this.

```
public class DimensionAttributeValueDto {

private long dimensionAttributeValueID;

private DimensionAttribute dimensionAttributeID;

private MasterData masterDataID;

private String chrValue;

private String intValue;

private String decValue;

private String datValue;

private DimensionAttributeList lstValue;

private Date startDate;

public DimensionAttributeValue() {
}

public DimensionAttributeValue(DimensionAttribute dimensionAttributeID, MasterData masterDataID, String chrValue, String intValue, String decValue, String datValue, DimensionAttributeList lstValue, Date startDate) {
    this.dimensionAttributeID = dimensionAttributeID;
    this.masterDataID = masterDataID;
    this.chrValue = chrValue;
    this.intValue = intValue;
    this.decValue = decValue;
    this.datValue = datValue;
    this.lstValue = lstValue;
    this.startDate = startDate;
}
```

Also, Don't forget to map the DTO with the Entity, using map method of Mapper.